# strech animation faster / slower in parts

Tags: animation

I have an empty object at the moment representing a planet following the path of an ellipse using the follow path animation constraint. I want the empty to be faster at one end, slower at the other end. Effectively faking the velocity of a satellite orbiting a planet in an ellipse.

How do I go about doing this from the point of just a follow path animation. I tried baking the animation 1 frame at a time, and then stretching the points in the dope editor, and stretching the f-curves, neither worked, they either skip oddly, in case of dope, or the orbits become malformed from the f-curve.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select your path and go to the path object data tab form the properties pane, scroll down to **path animation**, there's the property **frames** which you can animate (hover and press i) to increase or decrease the amount of frames required to traverse the path at any given time.
So for example, if the value is at 100 at first, but starting from frame 50 you want the movement to be slower until frame 100, then at frame 50 you would create a keyframe (still at value 100), at frame 100 you would create another keyframe with value 150 for example.